# Uncaught exception: unexpected response data (uploading to the wrong URL?) in Youtube IOS API

Tags: ios, google-api, youtube-api, iphone-6

I'm tried to upload video in youtube using youtube IOS api. i reproduced issues for new user's. But i dont know how to fix it.

I have created new gemail id and tried upload video using youtube api. I'm geeting below error. to  old gmail user's they logged already youtube. But i tried my old gmail id Video was uploaded successfully.
Please help me what is the issues

```
2015-06-01 18:01:11.328 myTestApp[1455:647598] *** Assertion failure in -[GTMHTTPUploadFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading:], /Users/test/sant_May19/Utils/ShareCloud/Youtube/GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.m:399
2015-06-01 18:01:11.337 myTestApp[1455:647598] Gosh!!! (
0  CoreFoundation                      0x29869007 <redacted> + 150
1  libobjc.A.dylib                    0x37ddcc8b objc_exception_throw + 38
2  CoreFoundation                      0x29868ec5 <redacted> + 0
3  Foundation                          0x2a567f17 <redacted> + 90
4  myTestApp                  0x0010dc69 -[GTMHTTPUploadFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 648
5  CFNetwork                          0x293aae29 <redacted> + 56
6  CFNetwork                          0x293aade3 <redacted> + 182
7  CFNetwork                          0x293aaed5 <redacted> + 36
8  CFNetwork                          0x292bec87 <redacted> + 78
9  CFNetwork                          0x2935c0d5 <redacted> + 60
10  CFNetwork                          0x292afa35 <redacted> + 60
11  CoreFoundation                      0x29778c6d CFArrayApplyFunction + 36
12  CFNetwork                          0x292af8ef <redacted> + 182
13  CFNetwork                          0x292af7b5 <redacted> + 216
14  CFNetwork                          0x292af649 <redacted> + 48
15  CoreFoundation                      0x2982efaf <redacted> + 14
16  CoreFoundation                      0x2982e3bf <redacted> + 218
17  CoreFoundation                      0x2982ca25 <redacted> + 772
18  CoreFoundation                      0x29779201 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
19  CoreFoundation                      0x29779013 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
20  GraphicsServices                    0x31012201 GSEventRunModal + 136
21  UIKit                              0x2cf1da59 UIApplicationMain + 1440
22  myTestApp                           0x001048e1 main + 224
23  libdyld.dylib                      0x38368aaf <redacted> + 2
)
2015-06-01 18:01:11.338 myTestApp[1455:647598] WARNING: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *) (GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.m:49): Uncaught exception: unexpected response data (uploading to the wrong URL?)
2015-06-01 18:01:16.406 myTestApp[1455:647598] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unexpected response data (uploading to the wrong URL?)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x29868fef 0x37ddcc8b 0x29868ec5 0x2a567f17 0x10dc69 0x293aae29 0x293aade3 0x293aaed5 0x292bec87 0x2935c0d5 0x292afa35 0x29778c6d 0x292af8ef 0x292af7b5 0x292af649 0x2982efaf 0x2982e3bf 0x2982ca25 0x29779201 0x29779013 0x31012201 0x2cf1da59 0x1048e1 0x38368aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Looks like the issue is really related to the GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.  This is a google module used to gain access to the you tube videos.  Search on issues with this utility and I believe you will find your answer.  Looks like there is plenty of information regarding how it uses authentication and keys that have caused issues for others.

Comment: @Mr.Soccer Thanks for your reply. but it working fine in simulator and iphone 5s.